# How do I create a table without repeating the header?

Tags: python, html, django, logic

I am working on a page that outputs the member's information in a table if the member meets a certain criteria. The problem I'm coming across is that the table header keeps repeating itself if there is more than one member that meets the criteria.

Here's the code

```
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-transparent">
         <h4>Members who list {{ instrument.name }} as their primary instrument:</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
         {% if not primary_users %}
           <h5>There are currently no members who list {{ instrument.name }} as their primary instrument.</h5>

                    {% else %}

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>HCMN Rating</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {% for member in primary_users %}
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'users:individual_member' member.id %}">{{ member.first_name }} {{ member.last_name }}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{ member.rating }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ member.area }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is a screenshot of the problem I am talking about:
[image: The header is repeated three times!]

Comment: The code sample refers to `primary` instrument, but the screenshot refers to `secondary` instrument.  You haven't shown us the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `<tbody>` tags out of the `for` loop. Same for `</tbody>`, `</table>` and `</div>`.

You want to have only `<tr>...</tr>` part inside the loop:

```
                        <tbody>

                          {% for member in primary_users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'users:individual_member' member.id %}">{{ member.first_name }} {{ member.last_name }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ member.rating }}</td>
                                <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ member.area }}</td>
                            </tr>
                          {% endfor %}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

In general, when doing loops and conditions, pay attention to html tags, so that you don't end up with unmatched tags.